# How to find out whether the repository(all branches) ever calls a specific function or not?

Tags: c++, git

I want to know whether a specific function(say `void foo(void)`) has ***ever***(you see the specific function may be removed some days ago by a specific commit) been called in the repository or not.

Furthermore, if the said function exists in the repository, how can know which branch or branches ***ever*** invokes the function?

Comment: You have highlighted the word "ever" as if that helps understand what you mean - and that actually makes your description ambiguous.   For example, are you simply looking for source files in the repository that call the function?   Or do you need to track occasions at run time when previous versions of your program running on client machines have called the function?

Comment: @Peter I mean the specific function may be removed some days ago by a specific commit

Comment: https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/8e8524550af6ccbbfd4ded73667ef352a9d7fb70/gitalias.txt#L542

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see if the word `foo` is present in your code in an individual branch or tag `xx` :

```
git grep -e foo xx
```

If you want to hunt for commits in your history where `foo` was added or removed :

- you can start with `git log -G foo --all` or `git log -S foo --all` : these will select for you the commits where `foo` appears in the diff (`-G`) or where the total count of `foo` changes (`-S`) -- see [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) for more details.
- add `-p` or `--name-only` (e.g : `git log -G foo --name-only --all`) will show the patch/the list of files narrowed by the filter
- once you have a commit, use the `--contains <commit>` of `git branch ...`, `git tag ...` or `git for-each-ref ...` to see what refs contain this commit

Comment: *If you want to see if the word foo is present in your code in **an individual branch or tag***.   Is it possible to search ***all the branches***?

Comment: Check `git help grep` : `git grep -e foo branch1 branch2 ...` one way to get all  branch names is `git branch --format="%(refname:short)"`, so `git grep -e foo $(git branch --format=...)`, or write a loop, or ...

Comment: I see. One more question, does this command still work if the file containing the target function has been deleted in a specific commit already?

Comment: (I am willingly turning that question around) what do you think the answer is ?